# NodeJS Create text file from string and send back to client

Tags: jquery, node.js

I tried

```
var text={"hello.txt":"Hello World!","bye.txt":"Goodbye Cruel World!"};
app.get('/files/:name',function(req,res){
res.set("Content-Type","text/plain");
res.send(text[req.params.name]);
});
```

and this is my client ajax call

```
$.ajax({
                    type: verb || 'GET',
                    dataType: "text",
                    url: url,
                    data: data,
                    contentType : 'text/plain',
                    success: function () { $('div#callForm button').removeAttr('disabled'); },
                    error: alert
                });
```

However no file is returning to be downloaded.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are not accepting the response client-side. The `success` callback of [jQuery.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) passes 3 arguments: data, status, and xhr (or any variable name you choose).

```
$.ajax({
  type: verb || 'GET',
  dataType: 'text',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  contentType : 'text/plain',
  success: function (data, status, xhr) {
    console.log(data, status);
    $('div#callForm button').removeAttr('disabled');
  },
  error: alert
});
```

Comment: I see ill add this piece to my code to see if get a file download after. Marking right for now thanks